# Other storage category excessive since iOS 8.3 update

Tags: ios, iphone

I recently upgraded to iOS 8.3 from 8.2 on my iPhone 5s and for a week my memory/capacity remained unaffected.  But then one day I checked my available capacity and it dipped to 2.1 GB from 10.6 GB.  Then today I checked again and the capacity dipped again to 1.6 GB.  When I plugged my phone into iTunes, the "other" bar memory was 19.5—it was never that high.  What could be the problem?  I have a Virgin mobile 5s, if that helps any.

Comment: How could we answer that? Is it syncing something? Is it iCloud, or other remote storage. Is it a game. The darn "Other" category only says it is not ID as Audio, Movies, Photos, Apps, Backup....

Comment: The “other” section tends to be full of Safari bookmarks, text-message attachments, calendar entries, Facebook stuff and so on.  So lets take a look in to Others. First: Open Settings -> General -> Usage, next Tap on any large app - The Documents & Data shows the total size of the data stored by the app.- Decide what to do!

Comment: On the phone itself go to Settings > General > Usage > Manage Storage and see if the list there helps track it down.

Comment: Have you recently deleted a bunch of photos? Deleted photos get stored for 30 days in a hidden trash folder which appears in the "Other" category.
There are also a number of people (including me) having similar problems with deleted photos consuming GB's of "other" space - could this be photo related?